# Where exactly does a JSP runs ? on the client side or server side?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I've read @BalusC's great answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095397/what-is-the-difference-between-jsf-servlet-and-jsp) but something is still not clear to me :

On the one hand , when I write a servlet , I do something like this :

```
        String addressPath = "/WEB-INF/results/employee/employeePage.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(addressPath);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

and then , the user sees the JSP page called `employeePage.jsp` on his screen . Doesn't mean that the JSP runs on the client's side ?

So the JSP runs on the client's side , or on the server's side (JSP = Java server page) ?

Comment: JSP (Java Server Pages) is a server side technology used for presentation layer for the web applications. It cannot run client-sided.

Comment: `JSP` runs on `application serve`r in `servlet container`, since it's converted to `servlet` before execution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The JSP runs on the server-side but it is very common for the JSP to serve, in addition to HTML (and CSS), bits of JavaScript which is then run on the client-side.

A very simple example would be a JSP including some Google Analytics tracker (which is in JavaScript) in the webpage served to your visitors.

Note that I'm not saying that all JavaScript is always run on the client-side: there's also server-side JavaScript. All I'm saying is that JSPs often serves JavaScript and that the JavaScript served by JSPs is run on the client-side.

Comment: Just bits of Javascript run on the client side? I'd say the whole HTML response is "run" (i.e. parsed) by the browser on the client side (although it is generated on the server side). You mean to say that only the Javascript parts are code to be executed by the browser, right? I guess the HTML is a bit of a grey area here, as parsing and obtaining a visual output could be considered "running" (as per the OP question).

Answer (score 5):

A JSP is translated into Java servlet before being run, and it processes HTTP requests and generates responses like any servlet. However, JSP technology provides a more convenient way to code a servlet. Translation occurs the first time the application is run. A JSP translator is triggered by the .jsp file name extension in a URL. JSPs are fully interoperable with servlets. You can include output from a servlet or forward the output to a servlet, and a servlet can include output from a JSP or forward output to a JSP.

Comment: Sunil, You have not answered the question: Does JSP run on the server side or the client side?

Answer (score 5):

i understand that i am late in answering this question, but may be it can help someone.

the JSP life cycle involves the following phases:

1) Compilation

2) Initialization

3) Execution

4) Cleanup

**JSP Compilation**

When a browser asks for a JSP, the JSP engine first checks to see whether it needs to compile the page. If the page has never been compiled, or if the JSP has been modified since it was last compiled, the JSP engine compiles the page.

The compilation process involves three steps −

1) Parsing the JSP.

2) **Turning the JSP into a servlet.**

3) **Compiling the servlet.**

When the JSP is converted into an servlet, it has to be executed at the server side to serve the request.

Answer (score 3):

JSP is a server-side technology built on Servlets. If you use a container like Tomcat you can see the Servlets generated form the JSP files. In essence the call `dispatcher.forward(request, response);` is just a call to another Servlet.

Answer (score 2):

The jSP is running only in server side.
it's the java code only 
the Developer's can easily make code in jsp.

the jsp is finally converted into a java servlet only.
when we use  `dispatcher.forward(request, response);` it will just redirect you to that servlet.